# Javascript regular expression | construct - possible inconsistency

Tags: javascript, regex

Maybe I'm not understanding something, but can somebody explain to me why the following code is behaving the way it is:

```
/^[1-9]\d*(\.\d{2})?$/.test('0.50') === false;
/^\.\d+$/.test('0.50') === false;
/^([1-9]\d*(\.\d{2})?)|(\.\d+)$/.test('0.50') === true; // <-- WTF?
```

What's going on here? As you can see the 3rd expression is composed of the first two joined by the `|` operator. Since each one tests `false`, isn't `false | false == false` ? Or am I missing a basic concept with regular expressions?

I've tried this in the browser, and with nodejs. Same result either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of precedence of operators.

Your expression is `^[1-9][0-9]*(\.\d{2})?` or `\.\d+$`.

If you do the following:

```
/^([1-9][0-9]*(\.\d{2})?)$|^(\.\d+)$/.test('0.50')
```

you will get `false` as you expect.

(Note extra $ and ^ at the boundaries).

More details: in your second part of last expression you no longer require `.` to be the first character.

Comment: I didn't realize that `^` and `$` had higher precedence than `|`. Thanks for making the explanation simple and clear.

Comment: Operator "precedence" has nothing to do with it. The regex engine simply processes each token one at a time from left-to-right. The original (erroneously written) expression simply has two global alternatives with the `^` at the beginning of the first, and the `$` at the end of the second. Another way to fix it would be to group everything between the two anchors, i.e. `/^(?:exp1|exp2)$/` Otherwise this answer is correct. +1

Answer (score 0):

When you use alternation like this, you must also enclose the different groups in `()`

```
/^(?:([1-9][0-9]*(\.\d{2})?)|(\.\d+))$/
```

Otherwise your regex behaves completely differently.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, but that isn't false | false. I'll add some more parentheses to make it clear what the third regex is evaluating as:

```
/(^([1-9]\d*(\.\d{2})?))|((\.\d+)$)/.test('0.50') === true; // <-- WTF?
```